# Change language during runtime using values from app settings in a Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, localization, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

The default mechanism in Store app for language localization is by reading the correspondning resources.resw file based on the machines regional/language settings. How can we  override this behaviour to make it read from apps settings(from settingsflyout) during runtime. 
Is it possible? or any other mechanism is available to achieve this?

I tried setting languages property .

```
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame rootFrame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();

rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages[1];
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
```

but this not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the App.xaml.cs file add this line to override primary language:

```
    public App()
    {
        // Override to english
        ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en";

        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }
```

Comment: This will take effect only during application launch. Is it possible to change language while the application is fully loaded and running.

Comment: Yes, try [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa).